# addTextChangedListener on Edittext of other fragment

Tags: android

```
    val SEARCHBAR = requireView().findViewById<EditText>(R.id.searchbar)
    //This is EditText from other fragment

    SEARCHBAR.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable) {}

        override fun beforeTextChanged(
            s: CharSequence, start: Int,
            count: Int, after: Int,
        ) {}

        override fun onTextChanged(
            str: CharSequence, start: Int,
            before: Int, count: Int,
        ){}
    })
```

`MainFragment` Has `EditText`
and `Recyclerview` in `ChildFragment` should be changed by `EditText` of `MainFragment`.

I did above code in `onViewCreated` in `Child Fragment` , but I keep getting `NullPointerException` Error.

How can I use `addTextChangedListener` on `EditText` of other Fragment?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by `other Fragment?` , is your `EditText` not present in the fragment layout file

Comment: @Nitish Sorry , `MainFragment` Has `EditText` and `Recyclerview` in `ChildFragment` is changed by `EditText` of `MainFragment`.